# $jquery - $.ajax XML - .find .text

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am new to jquery and ajax so forgive my lack of professional statements.

I have load my XML file into, `success: function(xml)`.

I then call:

```
$(xml).find("name").each (function() {
    var name = '<li>name: ' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>';
    $('#name').append(name);
});
```

This work so much as I get 3 new `<li>` elements on my page as I would expect. What I do not see however is the text between `<name>Network</name>` tags.

I replaced the `$(find)` method with (xml) just to see what would happen and it returned all 3 names into all 3 `<li>` (close but no cigar!)

I suspect the `$(this)` method I am using is wrong some how but a little confused as to what I have done wrong.

Any pointers in the right direction please?

Edit--

XML Snippet:

```
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:getAccountsResponse>
            <Accounts>
                <acc??ountId>1</accountId>
                <address/>
                <city/>
                <country/>
                <creationDate>2012-04-11T00:00:00+01:00</creationDate>
                <description/>
                <fax/>
                <name>Network</name>
                <origin>??Support_4</origin>
                <phone/>
                <postalCode/>
                <state/>
                <webSite/>
            </Accounts>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML please. I suspect `$(this).find("name").text()` should just be `$(this).text()`.

Answer (score 2):

Given your XML structure replace this line:

```
var name = '<li>name: ' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>';
```

With this:

```
var name = '<li>name: ' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
```

This is because inside the `each()` loop, the `this` keyword will already refer to the `<name />` element, so there is no need to `find()` it.